# Logic level switch controlled via ground (0 V)

Tags: switches, relay, dc-dc-converter, logic-level, 7805

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbkeJt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My goal: to convert a ground signal pulse into a +5 V signal pulse.

My question: How on earth do I do this?

Backstory: My Jeep ZJ factory doorlocks operate using 5 V logic. My aftermarket alarm uses a pulsed (momentary) ground signal for both the lock and unlock feature (two separate wires).

I'm attempting to use those ground pulses to mimic the function of the native door lock/unlock switch inside the vehicle. The native circuit board inside the doorlock module uses a switched ground to "unlock" and +5 V is used to "lock" the doors. I am attempting to get the aftermarket (two switched ground wires) to communicate with the native circuit board (one switched ground and one switched +5 V).

The current is tiny because these signals drive relays on the circuit board.

Initially I was going to use a 7805 to switch/reduce a constant +12 V signal to +5 V.  I thought that I could use the momentary ground signal on the base of the 7805 so that it would only "turn on" and supply +5 V when the ground/base was momentarily pulsed (which worked), but the problem is that when the system is idle (when +12 V is on the input and the base is not grounded) there is +12 V on the output terminal of the 7805. Therefore this will not work because the output terminal MUST be at 0 V when at rest, otherwise it would always be sending a lock signal.

Is there a logic-level relay that completes a circuit ONLY when a ground is supplied to it? If so, then I can use the +5 V on the circuit board as a source and not have to reduce from 12 V to 5 V.

With an electro-mechanical relay this would be simple but these component-level transistors are a little more difficult to grasp for me.

UPDATE: I just wanted to say "Wow"! I asked a question and within 15 minutes, 4 people jumped in and helped. Thank you, everyone! This place is great!

Comment: The term "applying a ground" isn't terribly clear in a system that we presume is ground-referenced. Please include some schematics to better contextualize some of the things that are ambiguous when given in text form.

Comment: What is a "ground signal pulse"? Are you just asking for an inverter?

Comment: *"The amperage is tiny because these signals drive relays on the circuit board."* If there are already relays on the board, why not use these for what you need? Also, you write: *"pulsed (momentary) ground signal for both the lock and unlock feature (2 separate wires)"* and then *"a ground signal is used to 'unlock' and a +5v is used to 'lock' the doors". Normally, I might assume a common ground and think you have two **additional** wires, plus ground. But now I'm wondering if one of these wires actually **is** ground -- or perhaps something else. Clarify, please?

Comment: Applying a ground = completing a path to ground (0v)...

Comment: @nanofarad - I've tried to add some more clarity to my original post.  I'm attempting to make a schematic to upload as well.

Comment: @Hearth -  I've tried to add some more clarity to my original post.  I'm attempting to make a schematic to upload as well.

Comment: @jonk -  I've tried to add some more clarity to my original post.  I'm attempting to make a schematic to upload as well.

Comment: @nanofarad - schematic added

Comment: @Hearth - schematic added

Comment: @ jonk - schematic added

Comment: You can use an inverter(digital Not).

Comment: I can't understand your schematic. your "native door lock/unlock module" doesn't appear to be capable of doing anything; all it can do is connect +5V to itself or GND to itself, which is pointless.

Comment: @hearth - the native module represents what is actually happening on the circuit board when the physical "lock and unlock" switches are pressed.  I have no clue what the actual logic is...it is a very complicated circuit board.

Comment: @HelenaWells - I know what inverters do...but that is about it.  I'm a manufacturing/mechanical engineer who's hobby is working on cars.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's what's actually happening, because that is not something that would ever possibly have any point to it.

Comment: @Hearth - I have verified the functionality by bypassing the switches on the circuit board using t-pins and jumper wires.  In other words, I can provide +5v or ground to the open side of the respective switches and the locks function just as they should.  When the "lock" switch is pressed, a circuit is completed that goes high (+5v).  When the "unlock" switch is pressed, a circuit is completed that goes low (0v).  This all takes place on a communication network that operates locks, windows, mirrors, etc.

Comment: But if all it does is connect high to high, it does nothing. I believe your description; I don't believe your drawn schematic.

Comment: @Hearth - Understood.  I've updated the schematic to reflect what I actually "know" is going on.  I've left one end of the switches unconnected because I have no idea where they go or what they do.  Thanks for your feedback, btw!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the schematic, using a transistor to switch +5V for 'lock'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give it a shot.  Regarding the transistor - I assume that the emitter is constant +5v and the collector will be my +5v output only when the base (lock signal) is grounded?

Comment: Anytime! Yes, your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up with.  I haven't connected any LEDs yet but otherwise it functions properly.

Instead of making assumptions about how the native circuit board operates, I simply created a device that completes one of two circuits based on one of two inputs.

I had to reverse the emitter and collector from the suggested design because I found that If I hooked the emitter to +5v then there was some continuity between the emitter and collector... even if the emitter was the only thing connected to anything.  I surmised that this would cause issues.  By using the "collector" as my +5v constant input instead, this issue was eliminated.

Now I'm researching how to turn my design into a small integrated circuit on a tiny circuit board with solder points for inputs and outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZrjAe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update:

Great Success!!

Turns out I didn't need any of the above.  Applying a ground directly to either CR204, or CR211 respectively, caused the locks to function as I desired...so I just soldered the alarm's door lock triggers (which are pulsed ground) directly to their respective points on the circuit board.  To do that I traced out each circuit to a ribbon cable so that I could solder onto larger joints.  I soldered one end of a two wire weather proof connector onto the board at the ribbon cable and then I made a small slot (with a dremel tool) in the housing for the 2 new wires to pass through.

At least the more complicated/unnecessary design functioned properly...and I learned some things...which is the most important part!